# What is the difference between connect and active states of BGP?

Tags: bgp, protocol-theory

What is the significance of having two different states in FSM when both try to establish TCP Connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BGP Peers start in **Idle** state. In Idle state, the peers have been configured to form an adjacency with one another other, but have not yet initiated or received any communication.

BGP uses TCP as it's transport. So for there to be a BGP adjacency, the first step is to establish a TCP connection. While both peers are in IDLE state, they will each periodically attempt to initiate a TCP connection at independent intervals (based upon when the BGP peering configuration was actually completed).

When one peer *initiates* the TCP three way handshake with a SYN , *that* peer transitions into **Active** state. This state indicates the local router is *actively* trying to initiate a TCP connection.

When the other peer *receives* the TCP SYN from it's peer, it will transition into **Connect** state. This state indicates the local router has received a TCP initiation from the other router, and is/has responded with a SYN ACK.

From there, both peers continue through the remaining states:  Open Sent, Open Confirmed, Established.

To summarize:

- **Active** state - local router has just *sent* a TCP SYN
- **Connect** state - local router has just *received* a TCP SYN from it's peer

The "initiating" BGP speaker's state transitions to form the adjacency will be:
`Idle`, `Active`, `Open Sent`, `Open Received`, `Established`

The "responding" BGP speaker's state transitions to form the adjacency will be:
`Idle`, `Connect`, `Open Sent`, `Open Received`, `Established`

Notice, only the peer which Initiated the TCP handshake passes through `Active` state. And only the peer which *did NOT* initiate the TCP handshake passes through the `Connect` state.

---

Adding some debugs which prove the behavior. This is Cisco router code Version 15.4(1)T.

This is from a BGP peering session between R1 (9.9.12.1) and R2 (9.9.12.2).

R2 is the initiator for this TCP session:

```
router1# show ip bgp neighbors | i ^BGP|host
BGP neighbor is 9.9.12.2,  remote AS 2323, external link
Local host: 9.9.12.1, Local port: 179
Foreign host: 9.9.12.2, Foreign port: 43876
```

Confirmed on the other Router:

```
router2# show ip bgp neighbors | i ^BGP|host
BGP neighbor is 9.9.12.1,  remote AS 1111, external link
Local host: 9.9.12.2, Local port: 43876
Foreign host: 9.9.12.1, Foreign port: 179
```

This is the (filtered) debug on R2, the initiator:

```
$ cat BGP-Peering_Initiator.txt | grep -e "TCP src" -e "went from"
*Oct 28 17:06:36.971: BGP: 9.9.12.1 active went from Idle to Active
*Oct 28 17:06:36.972:     TCP src=43876, dst=179, seq=1526684246, ack=0, win=16384 SYN
*Oct 28 17:06:36.975:     TCP src=179, dst=43876, seq=2072809595, ack=1526684247, win=16384 ACK SYN
*Oct 28 17:06:36.975:     TCP src=43876, dst=179, seq=1526684247, ack=2072809596, win=16384 ACK
*Oct 28 17:06:36.977: BGP: 9.9.12.1 active went from Active to OpenSent
*Oct 28 17:06:36.982:     TCP src=43876, dst=179, seq=1526684247, ack=2072809596, win=16384 ACK PSH
*Oct 28 17:06:36.985:     TCP src=179, dst=43876, seq=2072809596, ack=1526684304, win=16327 ACK
*Oct 28 17:06:36.985:     TCP src=179, dst=43876, seq=2072809596, ack=1526684304, win=16327 ACK PSH
*Oct 28 17:06:36.985: BGP: 9.9.12.1 active went from OpenSent to OpenConfirm
*Oct 28 17:06:36.985:     TCP src=43876, dst=179, seq=1526684304, ack=2072809653, win=16327 ACK PSH
*Oct 28 17:06:36.987:     TCP src=179, dst=43876, seq=2072809653, ack=1526684304, win=16327 ACK PSH
*Oct 28 17:06:36.987: BGP: 9.9.12.1 active went from OpenConfirm to Established
```

And this is the (filtered) debug on R1, the responder:

```
$ cat BGP-Peering_Responder.txt | grep -e "TCP src" -e "went from"
*Oct 28 17:06:36.973:     TCP src=43876, dst=179, seq=1526684246, ack=0, win=16384 SYN
*Oct 28 17:06:36.974:     TCP src=179, dst=43876, seq=2072809595, ack=1526684247, win=16384 ACK SYN
*Oct 28 17:06:36.976:     TCP src=43876, dst=179, seq=1526684247, ack=2072809596, win=16384 ACK
*Oct 28 17:06:36.976: BGP: 9.9.12.2 passive went from Idle to Connect
*Oct 28 17:06:36.983:     TCP src=43876, dst=179, seq=1526684247, ack=2072809596, win=16384 ACK PSH
*Oct 28 17:06:36.984:     TCP src=179, dst=43876, seq=2072809596, ack=1526684304, win=16327 ACK
*Oct 28 17:06:36.984: BGP: 9.9.12.2 passive went from Connect to OpenSent
*Oct 28 17:06:36.984: BGP: 9.9.12.2 passive went from OpenSent to OpenConfirm
*Oct 28 17:06:36.985:     TCP src=179, dst=43876, seq=2072809596, ack=1526684304, win=16327 ACK PSH
*Oct 28 17:06:36.986:     TCP src=179, dst=43876, seq=2072809653, ack=1526684304, win=16327 ACK PSH
*Oct 28 17:06:36.986:     TCP src=43876, dst=179, seq=1526684304, ack=2072809653, win=16327 ACK PSH
*Oct 28 17:06:36.986: BGP: 9.9.12.2 passive went from OpenConfirm to Established
```

Comment: You actually have the Active and Connect states backwards. For example, The RFC says this about the Active state: "_Active State: In this state, BGP FSM is trying to acquire a peer by **listening for**, and accepting, a TCP connection._" Also, "_Connect State: In this state, BGP FSM is waiting for the TCP connection to be completed._" Having sent the TCP SYN.

Comment: Hi @RonMaupin . I don't think I do. I got curious after writing it out and labbed it out, and it confirms the Active/Connect states work as I described them.  I'll try to put together "neat" debug output and add it to the answer.

Comment: This is what Cisco says: "_**Connect** In this state, BGP initiates the TCP connection._"

Comment: @RonMaupin Just added the debugs, see above.  Also, I'm much more concerned with what Cisco *does* than what Cisco *says*. Feel free to tell me if you see/suspect that I'm interpreting the debugs incorrectly.

Comment: Looking at it, the only thing I see is the responder went from Idle to Connect *after* the TCP connection completed. In my answer I said it was after sending the SYN/ACK. It seems it actually transitions after receiving the final ACK.

Comment: I would interpret the line
    "Oct 28 17:06:36.971: BGP: 9.9.12.1 active went from Idle to Active"
as R1 is going from Idle to Active.
Since R2 is initiating the TCP session, this would confirm @RonMaupins view.

Comment: @MathiasWeidner That output is from R2, stating that *the adjacency with R1 (`.1` IP) has moved from Idle to Active* -- not that *R1 is going to Active state*. Notice, also that the debug happened before the TCP three way handshake. Which confirms R2 was the initiator of the TCP connection, and was *Actively* trying to initiate a connection. On the other side, R1 (the responder) goes from Idle to Connect *after* the three way handshake.

Comment: @Eddie I have yet to learn about BGP, that's why the question caught my attention in the first place.
Then I saw two diametral opposed views in the answers and tried to make sense of it.
The example is from Cisco routers and your interpretation of the debug output suggests that the Cisco implementation of BGP assigns different states as the RFC.
That's why I suggested an interpretation that would reconcile the Cisco debug output with the RFC.
Anyway, I haven't dealt that much with BGP yet to form a well-founded opinion here.

Comment: @MathiasWeidner Sure, and I appreciate the attempt to reconcile the differences. In fairness, I agree, the Cisco behavior doesn't seem to match the RFC. I don't ready have access to other vendor platforms to run more tests to see if maybe we're misunderstanding the RFC. That section of the RFC isn't particularly easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

TCP creates a connection between two peers, and BGP uses TCP. One TCP peer will try to connect to the other TCP peer, and this is the `connect` state. One peer may listen for a connection (especially after a failed connection attempt on its part), and this is the `active` state.

BGP has several states, and each is clearly documented in *[RFC 4271, A Border Gateway Protocol 4 (BGP-4)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271)*. The descriptions of the states and moving from one to another (and/or back) is really too large to discuss here. Below is an image that describes the BGP Finite State Machine (FSM):

[image]

[The RFC has full description of the various states of the FSM and what happens in each stage](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#section-8.2.2).

Starting with the Idle state, when a ManualStart or AutomaticStart event happens on the system, it changes its state to Connect, but the passive versions of those events (ManualStart_with_PassiveTcpEstablishment or AutomaticStart_with_PassiveTcpEstablishment) happens, then it changes its state to Active. Basicially, when it is told to connect to a peer, it changes to Connect, but when told to listen for a peer, it changes to Active.

When in the Connect state, if the TCP connection fails, it changes its state to Active to listen for a connection from the peer.

When in the Active state, and the ConnectRetryTimer_Expires event happens, then it tries the TCP connection and goes into the Connect state.

There really is a lot more to it than that, but it is far too large for a site like this.

Comment: A very beautifully explained article for BGP FSM. Cisco has never explained it the way it is shown in the debugs. Since Connect state is achieved only after the TCP session is complete on the server (router whose local port =179), i don't see any relation between connectretry timer and connect state. I think connectretry timer should be used between Active and Idle state. Because the initator went into Active state just before sending the first SYN pkt.